# Multiple Set-cookie headers in HTTP

Tags: http, browser, http-headers

I'm writing a small class that acts as a very basic HTTP client.  As part of a project I'm working on, I'm making it cookie aware.  However, it's unclear to me what happens when my client receives multiple "Set-Cookie" headers with the same key but different values are set.

For example,

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=abc; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=def; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ghi; path=/
```

Which one of these is supposed to be the value for PHPSESSID?  This usually ends up happening when you call session_start() and then session_regenerate_id() on the same page.  Each will set its own header.  All browsers seem to do okay with this, but I can't seem to get my client to pick the right one out.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 36):

[RFC 6265 section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2) states:

> If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name,
> domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already stored,
> the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new cookie.
> Notice that servers can delete cookies by sending the user agent a
> new cookie with an Expires attribute with a value in the past.

So I would process the headers in order given and overwrite them if there is a duplicate.  So in your case you would have just one PHPSESSID=ghi.

Answer (score 28):

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) states:

> Servers SHOULD NOT include more than one Set-Cookie header field in the same response with the same cookie-name.

I would therefore be very concerned if your service sends multiple Set-Cookie headers with the same key.  Especially because I have seen user agents and proxies behave unexpectedly - sometimes taking the value of the first header, sometimes rearranging headers.

As a client, the typical user agent behavior seems to be to take the value of the last header.  The RFC alludes to that behavior with this statement:

> If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name, domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already stored, the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new cookie.

Comment: It's not saying should not send multiple set-cookie headers.  It's saying multiple headers with the same cookie-name.

Comment: Fixed, in case it wasn't clear from the OP's context.