# Overriding a sent cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, setcookie, period

How do browsers act when the HTTP response contains two `Set-cookie` headers, and only `expires` and `Max-Age` are different between the two (same name, value, domain and path etc..)?

I need to extend session lifetime. The system calls `setcookie` with the cookie name `session_name()`, with a period I want to extend.

I cannot change that value in the code directly, but I can call `setcookie` afterwords with the my customized period. This causes the `Set-Cookie` header to be sent twice, with my modified period comes next (because I called `setcookie` after it was called)

In Chrome, it handled it by overriding, so the second one override the first and that is what I need.

However, I do suspect this will happen with every browser or if this is a standard behavior. Is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Set-cookie headers in HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806132/multiple-set-cookie-headers-in-http)

Comment: DUPLICATE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806132/multiple-set-cookie-headers-in-http

The answer is Yes it takes the latest.